# TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined at runMicrotasks

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

I'm currently facing an issue that i don't know anything about.

I'm building an app using Next.JS, TailwinCSS, Npm and vercel to deploy.

In fact, when i start the server, i'm having this issue (also when deploying on Vercel):

```
    ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/react-loader-spinner/dist/loader/css/react-spinner-loader.css
TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
```

I had some issues at a time, with TailwindCSS because of certain properties not running, i don't know if the reinstallation had an impact or not...?

If someone have any idea,
Thank you for your time !

Comment: check you dependencies concerned with `react-spinner-loader`. and check why `theme` property from `undefined` in the any of your project.

Comment: @JAKK I have the same stack (plus Storybook) and issue. Have tried removing node_module as suggested below but still the same error. Have you had any joy?

Comment: I clearly don’t know why, but I cleanly uninstalled Tailwind CSS & reinstall, cleaned cache and all was good :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

> '@tailwindcss/jit': {}

- with

> *tailwindcss: {}*

in your postcss.config.js like

```
   // https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors
    module.exports = {
      plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {}, // remove '@tailwindcss/jit': {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    }
```

Then update tailwind.config.js and add

> mode:'jit'

```
module.exports = {
  mode:'jit', // <= add here 
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*. {js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Also check this [pr](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/27042/files) and [issue](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/4081)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing an similar issue.

My error log is following.
It was occured after updating packages.

```
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[2]!./styles/globals.css
TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of undefined
```

I could not understand what happen.

So I do

```sh
rm -r node_modules
rm package-lock.json
rm -r .next
git reset --hard <commit id>
npm install
npm start
```

If that doesn't work, `git clone` again may work.

How about this?

Thanks!